# Replace empty spaces with ### from Text between " " in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

I have a string like this one `text more text "empty space"`.
How can I replace the space in `"empty space"` and only this space with ###?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: I only want to replace the empty spaces form the text between "". So the reult shoould look like text more text "empty###space"

Comment: This question is overall confusing. Instead of "text more text".. provide a real Exaple. "This is a text string and I'd like it to be changed somehow." This display the string exactly how you want it changed.

Comment: @user1067506: Please answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, with no regular expressions:

```
$text = 'foo bar "baz quux"';
$parts = explode('"', $text);
$inQuote = false;

foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if ($inQuote) { $part = str_replace(' ', '###', $part); }
    $inQuote = !$inQuote;
}

$parsed = implode('"', $parts);
echo $parsed;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = 'text more text "empty space"';
$search = 'empty space';
str_replace($search, 'empty###space', $string);
```

Comment: @George The text will change..."empty space" was only for demonstrating

Comment: @user1067506 I see from your comment, this wasn't clear in original post. Working on another solution.

Comment: @George Yep. Maybe I did not describe the problem exactly. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$somevar = "empty space";
$pattern = "/\s/";
$replacement = "###";
$somevar2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $somevar);
echo $somevar2;
```

Comment: this will do all spaces.  if this is in a big blob of text, pattern would be empty\sspace and replacement would be empty###space

Comment: Please have a look at my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "My String is great";
$replace = " ";
$replace_with = "###";

$new_string = str_replace($replace, $replace_with, $string);
```

This should do it for you. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: After seeing the updated question, George has provided the correct answer.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after you comments**

Maybe it's not the best solution, but you can do it like this:

```
$string = 'text more text "empty space"';
preg_match('/(.*)(".*?")$/', $string, $matches);
$finaltext = $matches[1] . str_replace(' ', '###', $matches[2]);
```